# Why can I use the same lambda for Runnable and Supplier Functional Interfaces?

Tags: java, java-11

Take the next piece of code

```
private static int counter = 0;

void some method() {
   Runnable a = () -> 1; // compilation error -> Bad return type - which is expected
   Runnable b = () -> counter++; // Here I am expecting to receive an error
   Supplier<Integer> c = () -> counter++; // this works - as expected
}
```

Also, below I understand why and how java differentiates between the 2

```
Runnable a = this::test; 
Runnable b = this::testInt;

void test() {
  counter++;
} 

int testInt() {
  return counter++;
}
```

So why is there no compilation error on the line with b from the first code snippet? Or should i say how java knows where to put the return statement? Is it just by looking at the method signature of the functional interface method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it just by looking at the method signature of the functional interface method?

This.  Java notices that the lambda is being assigned to a `Runnable` and infers that there should not be a `return`.